# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.net.http.httpresponsemessage' to 'system.web.httpresponse'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a `web service` in `visual studio 2015` using `MySQL` databases. I want implement only a GET method using `HTTP`. Now when I am doing it I cam accross and error. Which is

`cannot implicitly convert type 'system.net.http.httpresponsemessage' to 'system.web.httpresponse'`

The point where it comes is below

```
public HttpResponse Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, mEntities.meters_info_dev.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Data found");
        }
    }
```

Below is the image

[image]

I couldn't find the solution for it. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Try changing the return type from HttpResponse to HttpResponseMessage as thats what you are making

Comment: I have changed it now it's giving me `{"Message":"No Data found"}`

Comment: There is insufficient info to pass comment on this - plus thats a whole new question and needs you to do a viable minimal reproducible etc..

Comment: @BugFinder, I have posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423283/web-api-not-returning-any-data-result). Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Directly it will not take the implicit conversion as expected But we can use HttpResponseMessage/HttpWebResponse type function to avoid the above issue. I have mentioned some sample code, it may help you.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("AddorUpdatePersonalInfo")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddorUpdatePersonalInfo([FromBody]PersonalInfo personalinfo)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await this._Personalinforepository.AddorUpdatePersonalInfo(personalinfo);
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
                return response;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));
            }
        }
```